# Unserialize a string in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have this object `a`:

```
a <- list(x = 1, y = 2)
```

I serialized and converted it to a string using the following code:

```
s <- serialize(a, NULL)
s2 <- paste0(s, collapse = "")
```

So now I have only `s2` and I need to get `a` again. I'm doing this, but I got an error:

```
s3 <- substring(s2, seq(1,nchar(s2),2), seq(2,nchar(s2),2))
s4 <- as.raw(s3)
Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: out-of-range values treated as 0 in coercion to raw 
unserialize(s4)
Error in unserialize(s4) : unknown input format
```

I also tried

```
> charToRaw(s2) %>% unserialize()
Error in unserialize(.) : unknown input format
```

I realy need `s2` to be a one-element character vector.
How do I get `a` back?

Comment: `serialize` is a low-level function. Why not use a higher-level wrapper, such as `saveRDS` with a `textConnection`?

Comment: Do you think It's better? I'm writing `s2` to a character column of a database...

Comment: To be honest, `saveRDS` works quite badly with text connections. I’d probably stick with your low-level solution. A better solution would of course be not to use a character column in the database but rather a binary blob (or better yet, to save structured data; but I’m assuming that this isn’t possible in your case).

Comment: Thanks! I cant' save structure data, since the object in question is an R model. But I found that I can use binary columns in the  database with this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683483.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.raw` doesn’t work as necessary for characters, you need to transform the hex digits into numbers first:

```
s4 = as.raw(as.integer(paste0('0x', s3)))
unserialize(s4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `dplyr` reproducible example using the technique in @Konrad's great answer

Start with some string / character

```
library(dplyr)
some_string <- 'something 123 something'
```

Serialize it

```
(serialized_char <- some_string %>% serialize(NULL) %>% as.character() %>% paste0(collapse = ""))
[1] "580a000000030003060200030500000000055554462d3800000010000000010004000900000017736f6d657468696e672031323320736f6d657468696e67"
```

Unserialize it back to string / character

```
(unserialized <- serialized_char %>% 
    {substring(., seq(1, nchar(.), 2), seq(2, nchar(.), 2))} %>% 
    paste0("0x", .) %>% 
    as.integer %>% 
    as.raw %>% 
    unserialize())
[1] "something 123 something"
```

And to make absolutely sure it worked

```
some_string == unserialized
[1] TRUE
```